# How to create automated test case in laravel

Tags: laravel

Is there any way to create automated test case in laravel. It means when I will run the test case it will open browser automatically, check the validation, submit the form etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite possible. From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#interacting-with-your-application):

> Laravel provides several methods for testing forms. The type, select,
>   check, attach, and  press methods allow you to interact with all of
>   your form's inputs.

A sample test case would look something like:

```
public function testNewUserRegistration()
{
    $this->visit('/register')
         ->type('Taylor', 'name')
         ->check('terms')
         ->press('Register')
         ->seePageIs('/dashboard');
}
```